# Dealing with mysql fetching forever

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with a **million records**. When i execute a particular query with a limit of **1000** ;

I get :

```
limit 1,000 row(s) returned 6.844 sec / 0.000 sec
```

When i execute for  **2,000 rows**, i get :

```
limit 2000  2000 row(s) returned    7.438 sec / 2.828 sec
```

But when i run the query for the for 4000 records or greater i see :

```
 7.922 sec / ?
```

Fetch has a question mark. I even had my computer up all night but the fetching was still executing.

SO i thought if getting some results using OFFSET,LIMIT. A Limit of :

```
0, 1000 worked
1001,1000 worked
2001,2000 worked
```

But a Limit of `3001,1000` fetched forever !

What is so different from a limit of 3000 and 4000 which won't execute ? not to talk of a million records which i plan to fetch. My query has multiple JOINS which can't be avoided.

Can looking at this benchmark give anyone a clue to how i can bypass such a problem ?

Comment: You obviously have your database configuration setup poorly. I would search google for the correct configuration for the database type you are using. Ensure you are using indexes etc. my database: limit 0,10000 - (1,754,997 total, Query took 3.1000 sec)